# Print copies - Prints the last job's amount

Tags: printing, printer, photoshop-cs5

Strange one here. Never seen this before.

When you print a document from Photoshop, it will print but it prints the number of copies specified on the previous job. For example:

1. Document 1: set print 2 copies - result: (previous amount)
2. Document 2: set print 1 copy - result: prints 2 copies
3. Document 3: set print 3 copies - result: prints 1 copy
4. Document 4: set print 2 copies - result: prints 3 copies

It isn't as if the queue is off by one because it always prints the right document. This doesn't happen in other applications like notepad or Adobe Reader when printing to the same printer. It doesn't happen when printing to a different printer.

I have rebooted the printer, removed/reinstalled the printer, restarted print spooler.

edit: I forgot to ask a question. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you asking a question to resolve the problem or just find out if anyone else has seen this or if it makes sense? If you want help, you should ask something like: "How can I resolve this?" If that is the case, then I would say, its likely an application problem. Have you checked the Photoshop support information or reinstalled the program?

Comment: I won't have time to be saving brushes and all this stuff with Photoshop. That's biting off a bit more than I can chew. Can you give him a call at 662-342-2884? His name is Jason and he will be expecting a call before 5:00 CST. Just let him know this is what Robert was working on earlier today.